# Why doesn't the MessageBox class have a default constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor

**Case 1:**

I am trying this

```
MessageBox m = new MessageBox();
```

And got compilation error

> 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox' has no constructors defined

**Case 2:**
Then, I have made a class without constructor

```
class myClass
{

}
```

and tried `myClass my = new myClass();`  This time **I found no error.**

Now, my question:

- **Why I am getting error in 1st case?**

Since, both are classes and every class have default constructor, then

- **Where is default constructor in 1st case?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The constructor may be `private` or `protected` in order to forbid direct instantiation. Use the static factory method instead. There is a static method `Show` in the `MessageBox` class.

Archil is right, too. If theres a explicit constructor defined, the implicit default constructor is not created anymore.

And regarding x0ns comments: Yes, it's also impossible to instantiate static classes. Don't use static classes, thats poor design (there are exceptions).

Comment: For example: MessageBox.Show( "My Title", "My Caption" )

Comment: Show is not a factory method. All code ends up being p/invoke. The pattern actually is a static class pattern, but the static keyword did not exist when messagebox was designed (pre-whidbey 2.0)

Comment: `MessageBox.Show` still acts as a factory: It creates something complex for you in order to reduce code duplication. It doesn't matter if your getting a handle to it or not or whether there is a .NET object created. It's just a special case because there's only p/invoke. Static class is no desirable pattern, if it's a pattern at all. It's just caused by all the native calls.

Answer (score 5):

In c#, evey class automatically has default constructor if NONE is defined. MessageBox defines other constructors, so it does not automatically have default constructor

Comment: It does have a constructor, according to Reflector.  But the constructor is not marked `public`.

Comment: MessageBox does not have public constructors http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx

Comment: That is what i said. `MessageBox defines OTHER constructors, so it does not automatically have default constructor`

Comment: That't not the same.. There's a difference between non-public constructors and non-standard ones, which are still callable.

Answer (score 3):

MessageBox is designed to be used as a static class - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(VS.80).aspx

You can make your class static using:

```
static class myclass {}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%27System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox%27)** has no default (empty) constructor.

A constructor can be hidden by setting its accessibility to something other than public.

The class' design declares that you can't use it as an object.
It only has static methods that can be used without instantiating an object of that class.

Answer (score -1):

In case 1, MessageBox is a static class, it has no constructors (update - it has a private constructor says reflector but the OP gave a misleading/incorrect compiler error message.) Static classes are defined like this:

```
public static class MessageBox { }
```

A static class can only have static methods, and as such is not meant to be instantiated.

In case 2, MyClass is not a static class, and the compiler generates a default constructor for you if you don't define any constructors.

UPDATE: to all downvoters: go compile up a project with a static class and examine it in reflector - it decompiles without the static keyword becuase there is no MSIL or metadata for a static class; the compiler (in .net 2.0 or later) generates an abstract sealed class with no constructors. The keyword "static" is just syntactic sugar. Additionally, in 1.0/1.1 of .NET (when MessageBox was created,) the static keyword did not exist for classes and the sealed/private ctor was the accepted pattern.

Comment: It's not a static class, according to Reflector. But the default constructor is private (so the class cannot be instantiated), and most of the methods are static.

Comment: @robert - the compiler error message "no constructors" isn't what you get for trying to instantiate a class with a private constructor. it's what you get for trying to instantiate a static class, which has NO constructors.

Comment: If you say the messagebox class has a private ctor, i believe you but I answered based on the compiler error.

Comment: That's what Reflector says.  It makes sense with what you said, because the private constructor short-circuits instantiation by masking the default constructor.

Comment: additionally, when messagebox was first created, there was no such thing as "static" classes; the keyword did not exist pre-whidbey. sealed class/private ctor was the de-facto static class pattern.

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense.  If you look at `System.Math` in Reflector, you will see that it decompiles as an actual `static` class.  The IL in reflector says that `Math` is marked `abstract`; the `Messagebox` class is not.  `Math` still contains a private, parameterless constructor (it is `static`).

Comment: Right, it might decompile in more recent versions of reflector as "static" but the keyword has no direct metadata equivalent. It is inferred from the abstract/sealed pairing.

Comment: I'm curious: since the original question was framed in terms of C#, not the IL it compiles down to, isn't more correct to state that MessageBox is not, in fact, a static class? If not, then when is it appropriate to speak of a class as being static?

Comment: @nick - in 1.0/1.1, if you sealed a class and gave it a private constructor, and if that class has no factory methods, and absolutely zero instance methods, then the intent was to make it a "static" class insofar as one could do so before the advent of the static keyword.

Comment: @x0n ever consider the downvotes may have something to do with your tone and word choice? Although I follow your reasoning, it's rarely OK to blanket people as "ignorant" and insult their intelligence with "Duh."

Comment: @ZaidMasud Removed ad-hominem. I was probably in a sh*tty mood.

Comment: I like your answer the best.  When you have a private or protected constructor, the error message is different.  It tells you that the constructor is inaccessible due to its protection level.